# Do I need do need to implicitly link between explicitly loaded shared libraries for interaction?

Tags: c++, dll, linker, shared-libraries, header-files

See the image below. The plugins implement an interace from the core library. (QtPlugin) The concrete plugin class is exported. The plugins should be able to retrieve the concrete plugin class instance from the core and call its methods. If I want to implement this kind of interacting plugins, do I have to link the plugins against each other?

I dont know what happens exactly when symbols get resolved. As far as I can imagine the process stores the resolved symbols. So as soon as the core library resolved the symbols the plugins can receive objects of other plugin classes and call methods on it, if they have the headers. Is this true (for all platforms)?

Some generic information on where symbols get stored and who can access it would be nice too.

[image]

Comment: "I dont know what happens exactly when symbols get resolved" - something for you to read up on right there..

Comment: those implicit links don't make any sense

Comment: Are you plugins loaded dynamically at run time, or statically at compile time by the linker?  It isn't clear from your question.

Comment: That what explicit linking is about. Linking at runtime. VTT why dont these imlipcit links make no sense? The plugin receives object from the core library and needs to know the type.

Comment: @JesperJuhl unfortunately it is highly complex and I coulnt find any good resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally you link against something, so plugin A links against Core library since it needs to know about the core implementation to function, the implicit link does not exist, there is not knowledge of plugin A inside Core (and there shouldnt be) so therefore core does not know about plugin A or B, and that means plugin B and A wont know about each other either without linking against each other.

in this kind of model you want to keep it agnostic between the plugins and use interfaces or abstract classes to communicate. (for example if a plugin inherits from Core with some pure virtual functions, another plugin can hold a pointer to it, and call functions on it without knowing the full implementation)

generally you link against something, so plugin A links against Core library since it needs to know about the core implementation to function, the implicit link does not exist, there is not knowledge of plugin A inside Core (and there shouldnt be) so therefore core does not know about plugin A or B, and that means plugin B and A wont know about each other either without linking against each other.

## Edit for comment:

In that case you could use interfaces, which plugins inherit from. so in the core library you make a class that is called ITerminal, which has a set of virtual functions (Update, Init, Connect, Open, whatever you need) without an implementation, and then pluginA can inherit from it and give the functions implementations. that way other plugins can hold a handle to ITerminal and call functions on it without knowing about the details of pluginA. to create it you need a factory for example Core::CreateTerminal, which will return an ITerminal (ITerminal* object = new PluginA();) now pluginB can call Core::CreateTerminal, which gives them a handle to ITerminal which has an implementation that Core chose in this case. to expand on it you can have plugins register themselves to core so core just calls a create function in the plugin, for example pluginA could register itself as a ITerminal class to core, then when CreateTerminal is called it will call the plugin to create a specific object. that way you can swap plugins in and out (have different terminals without changing Core or other plugins)

Comment: I want to allow plugin interdependencies. The dependencies will be known at runtime. libcore makes sure that dependencies are loaded before the dependents and injects the dependencies. Use case hard dependencies: A is responsible for all terminal stuff. B needs to open a terminal. Use case optional dependencies: A provides an interface to register handlers, B wants to register one.  The question is how to implement it with cpp.

Comment: since it was a bit long I updated the answer to include feedback on your comment

Comment: I appreciate your help but the core must be independent of the interfaces. I just tested it. Hard decencies are "easy" by linking to the other plugins. However optional dependencies are difficult since I cannot link them because the linker makes them a hard dependency.

Comment: Dll would be optional, .lib is not

Comment: All of them are shared libraries. However gcc complains about missing symbols at link time, which would be available at runtime